# Why did The Doctor need to burn a star to say goodbye to Rose Tyler?

Tags: doctor-who

In the end of season 2 of *Doctor Who* (2005), The Doctor needed enormous power to open the rift to the parallel universe to say goodbye to Rose. So, he burned up a star.

I don't know what burning a star means (as a star's already burning), but he also said something about orbiting a supernova, meaning he was drawing power from an exploding star (which can outshine 10 billion suns).

But why would he need that? Doesn't the TARDIS have a more efficient power source?

In the *Journey to the Centre of the TARDIS* episode, we saw the *Eye of Harmony*, the power source of TARDIS. It was created by suspending time around an exploding star in the act of becoming a black hole, harnessing the potential energy of a collapse that would never occur. From the episode, there were several exploding stars which were in *permanent* decaying states. Isn't this some kind of unlimited power source?

The collapse of star would never happen, but yet potential energy of collapse was the output. It looks to me a kind of time loop situation. At any given point of time outside *Eye of Harmony*, shouldn't *Eye of Harmony* give literally infinite energy as there'd be infinite number of collapse energy harness cycle by then?

Why exactly did The Doctor need to use an external, less-efficient power source in that case?

Comment: i assume that since the tardis power wasnt enough, and their are no more tardis/unable to created another tardis power source, having a star go supernova was the only way he had to get extra power. and it was getting into the parallel universe that cost so much power, (also i thought their was some problem were the tardis power source wouldnt allow him to do it, not that it didnt have the x amount of power it litterally couldnt)

Comment: I think you've answered your own question. He *caused* a sun to go supernova to use as a power source.

Comment: I think the out-of-universe explanation, that they had to make it clear Rose was nigh-unreachable and that an actual reunion was not possible, probably trumps any in-universe explanation.

Comment: "literally infinite energy" made my intellect hurt -.-

Comment: @Lightness Haha.. Yeah, that should hurt coz it's Wibbly-Wobbly stuff. Don't forget, that thing almost destroyed the universe (which is infinite) before The Doctor rebooted the universe.

Comment: @SachinShekhar: The universe is not infinite. Stop saying that everything is infinite.

Comment: @Lightness Your logic is not even 17th century or even Aristotelian. Everyone believed in infinite universe from ancient times.

Comment: @SachinShekhar: I don't really care what ancient people thought about the nature of the Universe; we know that the observable universe is not infinite (the key point in this case as you cannot travel into an unobservable part of the universe nor can you have information to "reboot it") and it is extremely likely that the entire universe is also not infinite.

Comment: @Lightness Haha.. Are you turning down all of cosmological theories? For Flat and Hyperbolic Spacetime, the universe is infinite. Universe doesn't have enough mass to have elliptical Spacetime..

Comment: @SachinShekhar: It's like you didn't read my comment. The finite nature of the _observable_ universe is the key here. It comes down to basic information theory, nothing more complex than that.

Comment: @Lightness The finite size of observable universe is defined for Earth and by Earthlings (thanks to finite speed of light). Why are you confining The Doctor to observable universe? Why exactly he can't cross that boarder which isn't any kind of physical barrier? He can go to a point from where Earth would no longer be in Observable universe.

Comment: @SachinShekhar: The observable universe is whatever you can observe from wherever you are. We are not on a magical planet that is the only place where you cannot see into infinity. Light travels at a finite speed; by extension, so does information.

Comment: @Lightness That's what I have already said. What's your point exactly?

Comment: @Lightness TARDIS destroyed non-observable part of universe too... Not just observable part.

Comment: @SachinShekhar: You're still not getting it. Never mind!

Answer (score 11):

As you pointed out, the energy output of the star at the center of the Eye of Harmony is vast, but finite. And with Gallifrey (as far as he knew at the time) dead and gone, once that power is gone, there's no way to get another. The Doctor has been able to use rift energy from time to time to recharge some of the power systems, but we don't know if those are linked to the Eye (think BTTF -- Mr. Fusion powered the time circuits, but the car still needed gasoline to run). If that's the case, then using the power from the Eye for anything other than time travel means one less trip the Doctor gets to make.

It's also worth pointing out that he wasn't using the power to *open* the rift. The rift was in the process of closing, and he was using the power to boost a signal through the last little pinhole before it sealed itself off completely. That being the case, draining power from the Eye might have been overkill.

So, it might have just been the Doctor being conservative with a limited fuel supply. Why burn off energy from the Eye when siphoning off a supernova would work just as well?

Comment: Plus this is his last chance to impress this particular girl.